# Missing data when selecting next 3 records after a specified one

Tags: sql, sqlite

Im trying to select the next 3 or more records outside the select query in SQL. Im currently using SQLite Pro 3.5.87 for this matter.

So I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM winners_night WHERE winner_1 > 86 ORDER BY draw_date LIMIT 3
```

This is the output I get which is wrong:

```
draw_date   winner_1    winner_2    winner_3
2015-01-06  87          40          95
2015-01-18  95          66          20
2015-01-28  96          25          94
```

Now, winner_1 which in this case is 86 has the draw_date set to 2015-01-05 so the desired output should be:

```
draw_date   winner_1    winner_2    winner_3
2015-01-06  87          40          95
2015-01-07  46          72          74
2015-01-08  30          71          94
```

Here is my Schema:

```
Table [winners_night]
    Fields: 9
        [row_id]: INTEGER NOT NULL
        [year]: CHAR
        [month]: CHAR
        [date_of_the_month]: CHAR
        [day_of_the_week]: CHAR
        [draw_date]: DATE
        [winner_1]: INTEGER
        [winner_2]: INTEGER
        [winner_3]: INTEGER
    Foreign Keys: 0
    Indexes: 2
        [sqlite_autoindex_winners_night_1] PRIMARY
            [draw_date] 
        [row_id]
            [row_id] 
    Triggers: 0
    Unique constraints: 0
    Check constraints: 0
------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have gaps in my ids and that's why I'm not using them to sort results.

Instead I'm using the draw_date to sort the results.

Hope you guys can help me

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design. A better design might have 3 columns (draw_date, winner_no, winner_id). Also, it hardly seems necessary to say, but it's meaningless to provide a result set with no dataset.

Comment: For every draw there should be 3 winning numbers and a draw date. I could readjust the design, remove some unnecessary columns etc... but i don’t see how that would affect the desired output. Anyway I’m going to do a test database with your advices and check the results. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a sub query:

```
SELECT * FROM winners_night 
WHERE draw_date > 
(
SELECT draw_date FROM winners_night WHERE winner_1 = 86 Limit 1
)
ORDER BY draw_date Limit 3
```

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: Thanks!! Your code did the job but there is a little hick up. It’s only showing me the results for the first 86 in the table though I have tons of rows with the same criteria. For example a simple:
SELECT * FROM winners_night WHERE winner_1 = 86 
Would return all the rows where the condition is met all over the table. That’s what im looking for with your fix. 
Is there any work around that fixes the problem?

Comment: I am not sure I understand.  Could you make it "winner_1 > 86"?

Comment: Yes it did the job, but it shows the results for the first row where winner_1=86. I thought it would show the results for all the rows where the condition is met winner_1=86 because I hace the same entry in several rows

Comment: So you want to know the next 3 winners after 86 won the first time?